# How to add a new value to a field which will depend of two other fields of the same registry?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have 3 columns:

```
grossWeight | tare | netWeight
```

the value of the first two fields will decide the value of the third field:

```
grossWeight | tare | netWeight
50            40     ?
```

i want the follow... grossWeight - tare = netWeight

```
grossWeight | tare | netWeight
50            40     10
```

how can i reach that with SQL ?

Comment: `Select grossWeight, tare, grossWeight - tare as netWeight from <table>`?

Comment: Yeah, it should work like that, but i want to save that value into the netWeight field...

Comment: Why store `netWeight` when it can be easily calculated?

Comment: Beacuse i will work with it outside of the database and that mean lets code for querries jejeje...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cqn do it with something like:

```
update yourTable set netWeight = grossWeight - tare;
```

Consider to use [triggers](http://www.databasedesign-resource.com/mysql-triggers.html) for more flexibility: when using a trigger you can configure it to be automatically excuted when `grossWeight` and/or `tare` are inserted or updated.

Comment: I use a trigger, adn that work see the code below:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `proyecto`.`bobinas_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `bobinas` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.peso_neto = NEW.peso_bruto - NEW.tara;
END       Thanks i`m new in SQL jejeje

Comment: Great! Keep coming on SO and you will make it perfectly with SQL :)

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid triggers